# Generate sentences according to custom vocabulary/rules

Tags: gratis, nlp, language

I’m looking for a tool that can generate text (natural language) according to a list of words and their syntactic/morphological rules, both which I specify.

So for example, I might add the word "table", put it in the category "noun", and select the plural construction rule "append -s".

The tool should offer a way to generate a list of possible sentences, using my vocabulary and the rules I created. It should also be possible to input a sentence which the tool should check for correctness (according to the vocabulary/rules it knows).

The tool must be gratis (and ideally FLOSS). OS doesn’t matter (but native GNU/Linux support is preferred). No hosted solutions (self-hosted is okay).

(I used such a tool with a text-based user interface some years ago, but can’t remember its name.)

Answer (score 3):

It sound like you are looking for [python](http://python.org)s Natural Language Toolkit, [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/). It fits all your requirements:

- Free (both Libra & FLOSS)
- Cross platform - Linux has python installed by default in most distros but installs are available for just about everything.
- Not hosted.
- An example of what you are looking to do can be found [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/generate.html) but looks like:

  ```
  from nltk.parse.generate import generate, demo_grammar
  from nltk import CFG
  grammar = CFG.fromstring(demo_grammar)
  print(grammar)
  for sentence in generate(grammar, n=10):
       print(' '.join(sentence))
  ```

> ```
> the man slept
> the man saw the man
> the man saw the park
> the man saw the dog
> the man saw a man
> the man saw a park
> the man saw a dog
> the man walked in the man
> the man walked in the park
> the man walked in the dog
> ```